# Create column containing the url of the hyperlinked text

Tags: python, pandas, hyperlink

I have a data source that has a column containing text that is hyperlinked. When I read at pandas, the hyperlinks are gone. I want to still get the URL of each of the rows and create it into a new column called "URL".

[image]

So, the idea is to create a new column that contains the URL. In this example, the pandas dataframe will have 4 columns:

1. Agreement Code
2. URL
3. Entity Name
4. Agreement Date

Comment: Could you add a few rows of the data as text so we can see how it looks like (e.g., load it into pandas and use `df.head`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my knowledge pandas doesn't have this functionality as there is an open feature request for hyperlinks [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/13439). Moreover you can use `openpyxl` to accomplish this task:

```
import openpyxl

### Loads the worksheet
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('file_name.xlsx')
ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name('sheet_name')

### You can access the hyperlinks like this by changing row number
print(ws.cell(row=2, column=1).hyperlink.target)
```

You can iterate row-wise to get all the hyperlinks and store in a new column. For more details regarding `openpyxl` please refer the [docs](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html).